# Json_encode returns Null Php/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a table with multiple rows where I want to encode all the rows with json.

I have been looking for other question  and solutions and I have tried lots of different approaches but json_encode still returns null

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'testBasParmak');

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pictures");
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows); 

    $error = json_last_error();
    print  $error;

$mysqli->close();

?>
```

output in terminal is

```
[]0
```

if I try this

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pictures");
    $rows = array("id" => $id,"name" => $name,"description" => $description,"url" => $url,"users_id" => $users_id,"users_id" => $users_id,"totalvoteup" => $totalvoteup,"totalvotedown" => $totalvotedown,"totalvoteneutral" => $totalvoteneutral);
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $row[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows); 

    $error = json_last_error();
    print  $error;
```

output in terminal is

```
{"id":null,"name":null,"description":null,"url":null,"users_id":null,"totalvoteup":null,"totalvotedown":null,"totalvoteneutral":null}0
```

Maybe it does not send correct query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer my database connection is mysqli but my query for `SELECT *` is mysql all I needed to change was mysql commands to mysqli

```
$sth = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM pictures");
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[]=$r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
```

gives the correct  output

```
["id":"2","name":"Jess","description":"who","url":"www","users_id":"705735067","totalvoteup":"0","totalvotedown":"0","totalvoteneutral":"0"},{"id":"3","name":"Jess","description":"who","url":"www","users_id":"705735067","totalvoteup":"0","totalvotedown":"0","totalvoteneutral":"0"},{"id":"4","name":"Jess","description":"who","url":"www","users_id":"705735067","totalvoteup":"0","totalvotedown":"0","totalvoteneutral":"0"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

`$row[] = $r;`

Should be

`$rows[] = $r;`

Comment: how embarrassing I didnt catch that. I have changed row to rows but it still outputs `[]0`and I can see all the rows of table in phpMyAdmin

Comment: @SpaceDust You mean `$rows` is empty?

Comment: @xdazz in terminal when I enter `curl http://website.local/selectpictures.php` it returns `[]0` zero is json_last_error code means no error while encoding

Comment: @SpaceDust Try to find out why `$rows` is empty.